# Do I have to be a caster to receive the bonus for "Ring of the Ram"?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic, caster-level

The *ring of the ram* has the following description:

> The force of the blow is considerable, and those struck by the ring are subject to a bull rush if within 30 feet of the ring-wearer. The ram is Large and uses the ring’s caster level as its base attack bonus with a Strength of 25. This gives the ram a Combat Maneuver Bonus of +17. The ram gains a +1 bonus on the bull rush attempt if 2 charges are expended, or +2 if 3 charges are expended.

If I am a 4th-level paladin/2nd-level fighter with effective caster level 1st, does that mean I only get a base attack bonus of +1? Or is "caster level" reflective of the CL of any PC that uses it? and in this way, does a rogue have +0 to BAB, etc. or would I have a "Caster Level" 6th because that is my CL?

Comment: Hey, I edited your question for some minor formatting; nothing crucial, but the quote box is better semantics and more readable, and while I was there I changed some other formatting to match how Paizo does things. ShadowKras has already answered, and it’s a good answer, but I do have a question—what do you mean by “I have a "Caster Level" 6th because this is my CL”? CL is generally an abbreviation for caster level, and a 4th-level paladin/2nd-level rogue has paladin caster level 1st, nothing at 6th. *Character level* is not usually abbreviated CL—if that’s what you meant you should edit that.

Comment: @KRyan Clvl and CLVL I've seen as short hand for character level in a variety of other games, so that might be where it's coming from as short hand.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### No, you use the ring's caster level

Magical effects from magic items, in general, use the item's [caster level](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items#TOC-Magic-Item-Descriptions), which is defined at creation.

> Caster Level (CL): The next item in a notational entry gives the caster level of the item, indicating its relative power. The caster level determines the item’s saving throw bonus, as well as range or other **level-dependent aspects of the powers of the item** (if variable). It also determines the level that must be contended with should the item come under the effect of a dispel magic spell or similar situation.

There are exceptions to this, like staves:

> Staves are an exception to the rule. Treat the saving throw as if the wielder cast the spell, including caster level and all modifiers to save DCs.

But for the [Ring of Ram](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/rings/ring-of-the-ram/), you should always treat the caster level as 9, as described under the item's statblock:

> **Ring of the Ram**
>
> Aura moderate transmutation; **CL 9th**
>
> Slot ring; Price 8,600 gp; Weight —

Comment: Technically, one **can** create a *ring of the ram* with a higher caster level if one desires, providing the creator has a higher caster level. The CL 9th entry merely means that *unless otherwise specified* (e.g. in loot tables and the like), the CL is 9th.

Comment: @KRyan by default, only potions, scrolls and wands allow you to set the caster level of the item.

Comment: @ShadowKras The rules actually say both. In a roundabout way, they state that you may create items at a lower CL than yourself (seeming to imply that the default CL of an item is actually your own when you Craft it.)  But they also say "For other magic items, the caster level is determined by the item itself." which is ambiguous.

Comment: Which would be the other reference? Excluding a FAQ answer that is kind of confusing, the other mention about it says that you can create items with a lower caster level than your own, not that you can set the caster level to be whatever you want. The general rule speaks generally (items can be lower CL), while the specific explains the details (potions, wands and scrolls can adjust the CL).